# Play youtube video in background in Android

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, android-background

I am making an app where i want to play YouTube video in background. As i refereed so many things and its denoted like it is not possible to play in background, but there is an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.datanasov.popupvideo&hl=en) which is doing that. So, there is any way to do that ?

Comment: Playing the video in the background is the default behaviour of a YouTube video playing inside a WebView (if you don't tell the WebView to pause). Not saying it's a good idea, but it's very simple to achieve.

Comment: But i want to play video where controllers are mine (like buttons of Pause Video, Play Video, etc).@KaneO'Riley

Answer (score 0):

> and its denoted like it is not possible to play in background

It is fully possible and even official YouTube client does so. The trick however is that Google disallows that unless you are paying them i.e. for Google Music (alternatively, if you are rooted, there's [module for XPosed](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.pyler.youtubebackgroundplayback) that enables that other way), so if you are playing using official player, it intentionally stops when goes into background.

> So, there is any way to do that

Haven't looked at that app but there should be no technical problem by playing video stream using other players and when doing so, not being affected by Google policy.

Comment: How to integrate it with my background service ?

Comment: integrate what exactly?

Comment: How can i integrate this Xposed module into my project's Service class ?

Comment: You most likely will not (see what xposed is: http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer ). also it requires root. But you may peek the sources - maybe there's something you can reuse

Comment: But for this the device have to be rooted. So, that what i do not want to restrict. Thanks @MarcinOrlowski

Comment: Yes, xposed requires rooting. So you can either use webview or other plaayer that would deal with YT stream. What google provides is useless in this case.

Comment: Actually why i am not using webview is because of i want to put my own controller (like button of play, pause, etc). So, do you know any player which can play YouTube Video?